# Fibonacci sequence: Show that $F_{4n-1} $is divisible by 3

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Show that $F_{4n-1}$ is divisible by 3.
I know how to prove the base case of the induction and how to prove what would happen if n is divisible by 3. Nevertheless, I can´t find a path to prove that for $F_{4n-1}$.

If the Fibonacci sequence is given as $F_{n}$ = $F_{n-2}$ + $F_{n-1}$

Should I start by using the definition of the Fibonacci sequence as $F_{4n-1}$ = $F_{4n-3}$ + $F_{4n-1}$ and try to get somewhere or am I going into a wrong path?

Comment: For $n=1$ we get $F_3=2$, so....

Comment: Yeah, this depends on what the initial values of the sequence.

Comment: In my town, $F_1=F_2=1$

Comment: Yeah, usually, $F_0=0, F_1=1$ or $F_1=F_2=1,$ but occasionally, $F_0=1, F_1=1.$ But my comment was really meant for OP, not your comment. @ajotatxe

Comment: Mod 3 for every term and get a cylic sequence

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The standard initial values are $F_0=0, F_1=1$. Other choices make beautiful formulas as $\gcd(F_m, F_n) = F_{\gcd(m,n)}$ look less elegant.

Comment: @Sara Welcome to Math SE. FYI, see [Fibonacci sequence divisible by 3?](/q/1478582), found in the "Related" section on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Use induction to prove the following proposition:

$F_{8n}\equiv 1\mod3$;

$F_{8n+1}\equiv 1\mod3$;

$F_{8n+2}\equiv 2\mod3$;

$F_{8n+3}\equiv 0\mod3$;

$F_{8n+4}\equiv 2\mod3$;

$F_{8n+5}\equiv 2\mod3$

$F_{8n+6}\equiv 1\mod3$

$F_{8n+7}\equiv 0\mod3$

Because $F_{8n+3}\equiv 0\mod3$ and $F_{8n+7}\equiv 0\mod3$, so $F_{4n-1}\equiv 0\mod3$

Answer (score 1):

$(0,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,1),(0,1,1,-1,0,-1,-1,1),...$

$\phi(4n)=\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^{4n}-(1-\sqrt{5})^{4n}}{\sqrt{5}\cdot 16^n}=$
$[(1+4\sqrt{5}+30+20\sqrt{5}+5)^n-(1-4\sqrt{5}+30-20\sqrt{5}+5)^n]/[...]$

$(36 +24\sqrt{5})^n-(36-24\sqrt{5})^n$

$3^n(12+8\sqrt{5})^n-3^n(12-8\sqrt{5})^n$

Yep.